# What does the z-score mean in plain English (in A/B split testing)?

Tags: ab-test

I'm relatively new to A/B split-testing and can't wrap my brain around the idea of z-scores.

I know that a z-score gives one an idea how statistically significant the result is that one gets from a split-test.

However, I found quite a few websites that explain A/B split-testing **without talking much about sample sizes**. These articles even suggested that the z-score itself would only show statistical significance if the datasets used to calculate it is large enough.

So I ran a one-tailed test. I made a modification to an element of a page and checked how the changes performed in terms of conversion rates. This was the result:

```
| Treatment   | Hits | Conv | %      | z-Score |
|-------------|:----:|:----:|:------:|--------:|
| Control     | 701  | 200  | 28.53% | -       |
| Treatment 1 | 699  | 228  | 32.62% | 1.66    |
```

Confidence (z-Score): **95.17%**, improvement of conversion rate: **14.3%**

However, I figured later that this result lacks two things:

1. I didn't define a desired minimum improvement in percentage in my hypothesis, e. g. "Treatment 1 performs at least 20% better than Control"
2. I didn't define a required sample size but just let the test run until a z-score >= 1.65 was reached (which I heard is a bad thing to do).

I then decided I want at least a **22% improvement** of my conversion rate and that I needed **2,046 datasets** to tell whether or not this goal was achieved (calculated based on [this blog post](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/split-testing-blog/how-to-calculate-ab-test-sample-size/)).

The hypothesis was then:

> Treatment 1 improves the conversion rate by at least 22% and I can tell with a probability of 95% that this change is not due to chance.

The final result (2,046 datasets) showed that Treatment 1 didn't improve anything really and that I can reject the hypothesis:

```
| Treatment   | Hits | Conv | %      | z-Score |
|-------------|:----:|:----:|:------:|--------:|
| Control     | 1020 | 305  | 29,90% | -       |
| Treatment 1 | 1026 | 308  | 30,02% | 0,06    |
```

**What I don't understand is:** What did the z-score of the 1,400 datasets tell me in plain English? What is it good for in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original z-score tells you that, if the treatment had no effect, there would be less than a 5% chance of obtaining the scores you did obtain.

However that test depends on having a random sample of the population of interest. You didn't have a random sample because you deliberately selected one that would have a significant z-score.

Even if you did have a random sample, you would by definition expect in about 5% of cases to obtain scores indicating a positive effect when there is no such effect in the population.

As the blog post you refer to explains, increasing the sample size increases the *power* of the test, defined as one minus the probability of obtaining non-significant results in the sample given that there *is* a real treatment effect in the population. The post chooses a sample that results in a power of 95%. This is somewhat arbitrary, though. If testing is cheap you could go for 99% or even 99.9% and be more confident of not having missed a real effect.

In this case your original z-scores are not good for much because they are not randomly drawn. However, a random sample of an arbitrarily decided sample size, e.g. 1000, *would* still be useful, but (compared to a larger random sample) there would be a slightly greater risk of not capturing a real effect in the population.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I get it now, even though this leads to a few more questions for me :) But I need to clarify one thing: You say "if testing is cheap you could go for 1% or 0.1%". By that you mean I should aim for a z-score that shows 99% or even 99.9% confidence? I'll try that next time, but I doubt I have enough traffic for that. To collect 2,046 datasets took me 33 days, which is a bit too long :)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer. I meant that you could go for a power of 99% or 99.9%. I did not mean to suggest you should go for a z-score that shows higher confidence. As I said in the answer, selecting a sample on the basis of the z-score it produces is what caused you to have a non-random sample in the first place.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with choosing a sample size that will result in 95% power. I just meant that the decision to take a bigger sample is always a trade-off between the extra cost (in money, time, server use etc.) and the benefit in terms of increased power.  There is always a possibility that a random sample will fail to show an effect when there is a real effect in the population; that's the nature of sampling. You just need to reduce that risk to what you find an acceptable level, given the resources available for testing.